# How to put var (array) to .find query?

Tags: mongodb

Here is an example:

**1st:**

```
var res = db.organizations.find({
    docStatus: {
        $ne: "delete"
    },
    isAuthorized: true
}, {
    _id: 0,
    guid: 1
}).toArray();
```

**2nd:**

```
db.users.find({
org: {$in: [res]}, active:true
})
```

How to use array variable from 1st query as part of 2nd query?

Comment: can you show what is the problem you are facing? show sample document of users collection as well.

Comment: i can see in your question no need to write in comment again, i am asking what is the error or problem you are facing?, can you post schema structure of both the collections in your question and show console.log of `res` response of first query.

Comment: Here is my answer, commenting here with code is terrible(( https://pastebin.com/pSPQBidQ

Comment: please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of stack overflow and see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question, after reading this links please edit your question and add this details in your question.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is to transfer 1st query to second. I tried it via variable:


```var res = db.organizations.find({
docStatus: {$ne: "delete"},isAuthorized: true},
{_id: 0,guid: 1 }).toArray();```



```db.users.find({ org: {$in: [res]}, active:true });```


But output format of first query has not readable format for second.

Comment: db.users doc example (db.users.org.id and db.organizations.guid - only one crossing field between collections):
```{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5e6b78aed511140001abc32f"),
 "active" : true,
 "org" : [
  {
   "id" : "131fa88f-a58e-4ac1-84c1-fac4ee587a33"
  }
 ],
 "auid" : 68
}```

db.org doc example:
```{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5ac4d9b732a6c32104700588"),
 "guid" : "131fa88f-a58e-4ac1-84c1-fac4ee587a33",
 "isAuthorized" : true,
 "auid" : 89,
 "docStatus" : "delete"
}```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.users.aggregate({$match: {active:true}},
{$lookup:
{ from: "org", localField: "org.id", foreignField: "guid", as: "org"}
,
{$unwind: "$org"},
{$match: {"org.docStatus": {$ne: "delete"}, "org.isAuthorized": true},
{$group: { _id: "$_id"}})
```